# Selenium New window instead of New Instance? Next row on CSV?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, google-chrome

I attempting to submit multiple entries into a webform behind a login/password. The data is from a CSV.

In Selenium (python), when my code finishes it loops back, opens an entirely new Chrome instance with a fresh profile, and then has to log in again before entering the next row of the CSV.

I dont want to store my password in the python file/CSV nor do I want to create weird looking traffic by logging in 10-20 times in a minute.

Any suggested code to open a new window/tab within the same instance of Chrome and to have the data entry move to the next row in the CSV without starting a new instance?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv




PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
url = "https://123.com"



with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:

        web = webdriver.Chrome()
        web.get(url)

        time.sleep(1)

        username = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/div/app-login/mat-card/mat-card-content/form/div[1]/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div/input")
        username.send_keys('joe@smith.com')
        
        companyaddressnum = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/div/form/div[2]/mat-card[2]/mat-card-content/div[3]/mat-form-field[1]/div/div[1]/div/input")
        companyaddressnum.send_keys(line[2])
```

Comment: please share your code with relevant format

Comment: shared to og post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling web = webdriver.Chrome() in the loop, that's why it's repeating multiple times.

**Check this code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
url = "https://123.com"
web = webdriver.Chrome()

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        
        web.get(url)

        time.sleep(1)

        username = web.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                    "/html/body/app-root/div/app-login/mat-card/mat-card-content/form/div[1]/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div/input")
        username.send_keys('joe@smith.com')

        companyaddressnum = web.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "/html/body/app-root/div/form/div[2]/mat-card[2]/mat-card-content/div[3]/mat-form-field[1]/div/div[1]/div/input")
        companyaddressnum.send_keys(line[2])
```

Comment: Welcome!  Just make sure you read below article before posting any question on stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask